# Undo a single select_lines

Tags: sublimetext2, sublimetext

Right now I have the following mapping to select lines forward:

`{ "keys": ["ctrl+alt+down"] , "command": "select_lines", "args": {"forward": true} }`

I'd like ctrl+alt+up to simply undo the last ctrl+alt+down.  Soft undo doesn't quite work.  If you select multiple lines quickly then the undo de-selects them all, instead of just the last one selected.

If there's no out-of-the-box way to do this then maybe I could map ctrl+alt+up to a set of keystrokes that deselects the current line and moves the cursor up one?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

this behavior bugged me a lot too, so I've just went and wrote this: https://github.com/kizu/undo_select_lines#readme

This overrides the “soft undo” action in certain context, so it would actually “undo” the single `select_lines`.

The only downside is that there won’t be redo and the history would be a bit dirty, but whatever while it works.

So, if you didn’t override soft undo in your key bindings, installing this command through git in your Packages:

`git clone git://github.com/kizu/undo_select_lines.git`

Or download it [there](https://github.com/kizu/undo_select_lines/tags).

would fix this problem for you. Otherwise, look at how it’s implemented in the source, so you should replace the keybindings for your “soft undo”.